# The & operator on a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I know that `&` gives the address of a variable.
However what does `&` do on a pointer itself?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int *p = &a;
    printf("%p" , p);
    printf("%d" , *p);
    printf("%d" , &p);
}
```

can you explain what each of the statement does. Also not sure about the format specifier of `&p`.

Comment: In the last one `&p` outputs the location of the pointer variable itself. But you used the wrong format specifier `%d`, it should be `%p`.

Comment: It does the same thing it does on any other type - it returns its address, in this case `&p` gives you a `int**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer `p` is also a variable and `&` operator, when used with pointer variable, gives address of that pointer variable. To print pointer use format specifier `%p` and, ideally, the argument passed to `printf()` should be pointer to `void`. So, you should do

```
    printf("%p" , (void *)p);
    .....
    printf("%p" , (void *)&p);
```

> *can you explain what each of the statement does.*

This statement

```
    printf("%p" , p);
```

will print address of variable `a`. [The argument `p` should be type casted to `(void *)`.]

This statement

```
    printf("%d" , *p);
```

will print value of variable `a`.

In this statement, the format specifier used is wrong, it should be `%p`

```
    printf("%d" , &p);
            ^^ 
             |
             +--> %p
```

when you give correct format specifier `%p`, it will print address of variable `p`. [The argument `&p` should be type casted to `(void *)`.]

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what you have written yourself

> I am new to c and know that & gives the address of a variable.

So the expression `&p` gives the address of the variable `p` declared like

```
int *p = &a;
```

`p` is an ordinary variable that has the type `int *`.

To make it more visible you could introduce a typedef name like for example

```
typedef int * T;
```

Then the declaration of the pointer p will look like

```
T p = &a;
```

So the expression `&p` is the address of the variable `p` the same way as the expression `&a` is the address of the variable `a`.

Pay attention to that you have to use the conversion specifier `%p` instead of `%d` with a pointer

```
printf("%p\n" , ( void * )&p);
```